# Should GAE Bloblstore be used in place of traditional Database

Tags: database, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am writing a web application that requires a database which will have entities like user, friends etc. Since **Cloud SQL** service is not free so i am looking for alternatives. **Amazon RDS** is one option, since they have a free tier which would suit my needs in the short term but before I get into it I would like to know more about blobstores.

Is it ideal to use blobstore to store such kind of information?
There are questions like:

1. how will the **read/write latency** be compared to a traditional db ?
2. if i start with blobstore and later i want to **move to relational db**, what are the problems that i could face ?
3. The most important of all is, if it is **ideal to use blobstore** in my scenario.

After looking at the documentation on google dev site I have found that blobstores are used to store large/medium files like images and videos.

Comment: How about the GAE datastore? Where will your application be running? You'll want the database close to your web server for latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't try to use the blobstore for structured data. That's what the [datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) is for. Blobstore is for unstructured data such as files.